# Three dice are tossed. What is the probability that $1$ was obtained on two of the dice given that the sum of the numbers on the three dice is $7$?

Tags: probability

Three dice are tossed what is the probability that $1$ was obtained on two of the dice given that the sum of the numbers on the three dice is $7$?

I think that it is possible to represent the values using dots and pipes, like so: `. | . | . . . . .`, which means the first has $1$, the second has $1$, and the third has $5$.

Next, I would suppose that the sample space would be $9 \choose 2$, since that would be all the possible positions of the $9$ characters.

Am I right? What should I do next?

Comment: If two of them are 1, then the third should be 5. So it's just number of permutations of 5,1,1, so $3!=6$, no?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo  The number of permutations of $5, 1, 1$ is $3$ since there are three ways to place the $5$.  Once the five has been placed, the remaining slots must be filled with $1$s.

Comment: Oh, Yeah! ${3!}\over{2!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost right, but the number of arrangements isn't $\binom 92$ because that would count some arrangements that aren't possible (you aren't allowed e.g. `...||....` because that would mean the second die showed $0$). In fact you only have $\binom 62$ permitted arrangements: there are $6$ gaps between the dots, and each pipe must go in a different gap.

Now all you need to do is count the number of arrangements with two $1$s and divide by $\binom 62$. Given that the sum is $7$, you have one of those $\binom 62$ possibilities and each is equally likely, so the probability is just the number of possibilities with two $1$s divided by the total number.

Comment: So, there is no real trick to it? Just physically count them out?

Comment: In this case that's easier than trying to find a trick because there are so few options (if you know what two of the dice are, and you know the total, then you know the third).

Comment: So, basically, the number of possible arrangements is 3 since the other die must have a 5, but it can be either the first, second, or third.

Comment: Yes, that's right.