# Help applying the Bayes's Theorem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayes-theorem

I am trying to solve the problem 22 from Chapter 10 of "Chartrand, Gary & Zhang, Ping. Discrete Mathematics. Waveland Press, 2011." (pg. 374).

> Three dice are tossed. What is the probability that 1 was obtained on two of the dice given that the sum of the numbers on the three dice is 7?

This same question was asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2545725/783364). So, I already know the answer. But I want to see it being solved with Bayes' Theorem explicitly.

Let,

$$
A: \text{one was obtained on two of the dice}
$$
$$
B: \text{sum of the numbers on the three dice is 7}
$$

Then,
$$
P(B|A) = \frac{3}{6^3}
$$
And,
$$
P(A) = \frac{3\cdot 5}{6^3}
$$
Finally,
$$
P(B) = \frac{15}{6^3}
$$
Because the ways we could get the sum of the numbers on the three dice to be seven is the coefficient of $x^7$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$ which is 15.

Putting it all together,
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{\frac{3}{6^3}\cdot \frac{3\cdot 5}{6^3}}{\frac{15}{6^3}} = \frac{3}{6^3}\cdot \frac{3\cdot 5}{6^3}\cdot\frac{6^3}{15} = \frac{3}{6^3}
$$

And that is not the right answer. Note that I don't just want the right answer or a better way to get it, I want to know how Bayes' Theorem will work here.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\frac{3}{6^3}}{\frac{15}{6^3}} = \frac{3}{15}.$

Comment: Care to elaborate? Which of the two probabilities is one and why?

Comment: When you calculated $P(A)=\dfrac{3\cdot 5}{6^3}$, among the $3\cdot 5$ dice outcomes that satisfy $A$, how many dice outcomes satisfy $B$: "sum of the numbers on the three dice is $7$"? From this, I don't get your denominator $6^3$ of your $P(B\mid A)$.

Comment: Well, the sum of seven can only be achieved given two ones as $1,1,5$ and $1,5,1$ and $5,1,1$. This is $P(B|A) = 3/6^3$.

Comment: Your $3/6^3$ would be $P(B\cap A)$, and you got it correctly by listing all satisfying outcomes. But for $P(B\mid A)$, the denominator is not the full $6^3$, but

$$P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$$

Comment: I see, could you explain a little in terms of intuition why the denominator is not the full $6^3$ and how might I avoid such pitfalls in future?

Comment: **To the OP**: (i.e. the original poster) : To the best of my knowledge, the only way to avoid such pitfalls is to address the underlying problem, which is that in order to learn Probability/Combinatorics, you have to *stretch your intuition*.  You are attempting to tackle a problem that requires an intuition that is more sophisticated than your intuition currently is.  The only way that I know of, to address the problem is for you to find the right Math textbook **for you**, on the subject, open the book to page 1, and attack.  ...see next comment

Comment: In this instance, the *subject* is Probability Theory.  A Math book that is the right book for others might not be the right book for you.  In my opinion, the only hard and fast rule is that the book has to have many, many exercises (i.e. hundreds).  This is because the real learning takes place in the exercises.

Comment: The combinatorial intuition is pretty elastic. I had the _sophisticated_ kind back when I used to solve these problems more often haha. Anyways, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a beginner to Bayes' Theorem, it is often useful to

- think in terms of favorable  sample space  and **applicable** sample space
- if you want to use probabilities, use what I call the "baby" Bayes' formula

Applied to this particular problem,

- favorable sample space  $=3$,
- applicable sample space  $=15$

and you can get the answer directly as $Pr = \dfrac3{15}$

And for using the "baby" Bayes' formula,

- let $A$ = two out of three die faces are $1$,
- let $B$ = sum of three die faces are $7$,

$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}= \dfrac3 {6^3}/\dfrac{15}{6^3} = \dfrac3{15}$